# How do you throw Lua error up?

Tags: error-handling, lua, throw

Is it possible to throw a Lua error from a function to be handled by the script calling the function?

For example the following will throw an error at indicated comment

```
local function aSimpleFunction(...)
    string.format(...) -- Error is indicated to be here
end

aSimpleFunction("An example function: %i",nil)
```

But what I would rather do is catch the error and throw out a custom error by the function caller

```
local function aSimpleFunction(...)
    if pcall(function(...)
        string.format(...)
    end) == false then
       -- I want to throw a custom error to whatever is making the call to this function
    end

end

aSimpleFunction("An example function: %i",nil) -- Want the error to start unwinding here
```

The intention being that in my actual use cases my functions would be more complicated and I would like to provide more meaningful error messages

Comment: [Lua code can explicitly generate an error by calling the error function.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.3)

Comment: @TomBlodget, make it an answer? ;)

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - It seems that the idea of writing comments instead of answers is quite infectious ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I noticed ;)

Comment: @PaulKulchenko I'd rather see this question deleted than to write an answer.  But, I did want to help the asker learn that intelligible documentation (which the Lua reference manual is) is a primary reference. I don't think that this question and any direct answers to it are helpful to others. If the question was broader then they would be.

Comment: @TomBlodget: But the error still gets thrown from within `aSimpleFunction()` I was already aware error throws an error but the stack trace is not coming from the caller

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The stack level of an error can be specified when throwing a new error

```
error("Error Message") -- Throws at the current stack
error("Error Message",2) -- Throws to the caller
error("Error Message",3) -- Throws to the caller after that
```

> Usually, error adds some information about the error position at the beginning of the message. The level argument specifies how to get the error position. With level 1 (the default), the error position is where the error function was called. Level 2 points the error to where the function that called error was called; and so on. Passing a level 0 avoids the addition of error position information to the message.

Using the example given in the question

```
local function aSimpleFunction(...)
    if pcall(function(...)
        string.format(...)
    end) == false then
       error("Function cannot format text",2)
    end

end

aSimpleFunction("An example function: %i",nil) --Error appears here
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`error` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-error).

```
error("something went wrong!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Catching an error is as simple as using `pcall`

```
My_Error()
    --Error Somehow
end

local success,err = pcall(My_Error)

if not success then
    error(err)
end
```

Undoubtedly you're asking how this works. Well `pcall` runs a function in a *protected thread* (protected-call) and returns a bool, if it ran successfully, and a value (what it returned/the error).

Also don't think this means arguments to the function are impossible, simply pass them to `pcall` as well:

```
My_Error(x)
    print(x)
    --Error Somehow
end

local success,err = pcall(My_Error, "hi")

if not success then
    error(err)
end
```

For more error handling control, see http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.3 and http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Function_dump/Basic_functions#xpcall